# dynamic reconfigure specific directory

Tags: ros-kinetic, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using

```
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(ros/config/params.cfg)
```

in my `CMakeLists.txt` of a package, some strange directories within the package are created and I don't know why. Here is my structure before a build (top level is the catkin workspace with the toplevel CMakeLists.txt).

```
├── CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
└── src
    └── pack_template
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── library
        │   ├── include
        │   │   └── lib.hpp
        │   └── src
        │       └── lib.cpp
        ├── package.xml
        └── ros
            ├── config
            │   └── params.cfg
            ├── include
            │   └── template
            │       └── template.hpp
            └── src
                └── template.cpp
```

I then use `catkin build` with this CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(pack_template)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  dynamic_reconfigure
)

generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
  ros/config/params.cfg
)

catkin_package(
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS std_msgs
)

include_directories(
  include
  ros/include
  library/include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  cfg/cpp
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC
  library/src/lib.cpp
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
  ros/src/template.cpp
)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "example_node" PREFIX "")

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node 
  ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
  ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR}
)
```

and my folder structure after a build looks (deleted some hopefully uninteresting things)

```
├── build
│   ├── (...)
├── CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
├── devel
│   ├── env.sh -> ~/catkin/dynamic_reconfigure_test/devel/.private/catkin_tools_prebuild/env.sh
│   ├── etc
│   │   └── (...)
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── libpack_template.a -> ~/catkin/dynamic_reconfigure_test/devel/.private/pack_template/lib/libpack_template.a
│   │   ├── pack_template
│   │   │   └── example_node -> ~/catkin/dynamic_reconfigure_test/devel/.private/pack_template/lib/pack_template/example_node
│   │   ├── pkgconfig
│   │   │   ├── catkin_tools_prebuild.pc -> ~/catkin/dynamic_reconfigure_test/devel/.private/catkin_tools_prebuild/lib/pkgconfig/catkin_tools_prebuild.pc
│   │   │   └── pack_template.pc -> ~/catkin/dynamic_reconfigure_test/devel/.private/pack_template/lib/pkgconfig/pack_template.pc
│   │   └── python2.7
│   │       └── dist-packages
│   │           └── pack_template
│   │               ├── cfg
│   │               │   └── __init__.py -> ~/catkin/dynamic_reconfigure_test/devel/.private/pack_template/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pack_template/cfg/__init__.py
│   │               └── __init__.py -> ~/catkin/dynamic_reconfigure_test/devel/.private/pack_template/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pack_template/__init__.py
│   ├── setup.bash -> ~/catkin/dynamic_reconfigure_test/devel/.private/catkin_tools_prebuild/setup.bash
│   ├── setup.sh -> ~/catkin/dynamic_reconfigure_test/devel/.private/catkin_tools_prebuild/setup.sh
│   ├── _setup_util.py -> ~/catkin/dynamic_reconfigure_test/devel/.private/catkin_tools_prebuild/_setup_util.py
│   ├── setup.zsh -> ~/catkin/dynamic_reconfigure_test/devel/.private/catkin_tools_prebuild/setup.zsh
│   └── share
│       ├── catkin_tools_prebuild
│       │   └── cmake
│       │       ├── catkin_tools_prebuildConfig.cmake -> ~/catkin/dynamic_reconfigure_test/devel/.private/catkin_tools_prebuild/share/catkin_tools_prebuild/cmake/catkin_tools_prebuildConfig.cmake
│       │       └── catkin_tools_prebuildConfig-version.cmake -> ~/catkin/dynamic_reconfigure_test/devel/.private/catkin_tools_prebuild/share/catkin_tools_prebuild/cmake/catkin_tools_prebuildConfig-version.cmake
│       └── pack_template
│           └── cmake
│               ├── pack_templateConfig.cmake -> ~/catkin/dynamic_reconfigure_test/devel/.private/pack_template/share/pack_template/cmake/pack_templateConfig.cmake
│               └── pack_templateConfig-version.cmake -> ~/catkin/dynamic_reconfigure_test/devel/.private/pack_template/share/pack_template/cmake/pack_templateConfig-version.cmake
├── logs
│   ├── (...)
└── src
    └── pack_template
        ├── cfg
        │   └── cpp
        │       └── pack_template
        │           └── templateConfig.h
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── docs
        │   ├── templateConfig.dox
        │   ├── templateConfig-usage.dox
        │   └── templateConfig.wikidoc
        ├── library
        │   ├── include
        │   │   └── lib.hpp
        │   └── src
        │       └── lib.cpp
        ├── package.xml
        ├── ros
        │   ├── config
        │   │   └── params.cfg
        │   ├── include
        │   │   └── template
        │   │       └── template.hpp
        │   └── src
        │       └── template.cpp
        └── src
            └── pack_template
                ├── cfg
                │   ├── __init__.py
                │   └── templateConfig.py
                └── __init__.py
```

Is there a way to define a target location to create these directories? I want them

1. to be created in the subfolder `ros`, where all my ros dependent things are.
2. the paramsConfig.h should go to `ros/include` not in `src`

Edit: There was a mistake in my original post, I edited the package structure. My plan was to put all ros-dependent stuff in `package_main/ros/`, hence there are an include and src directory. Second my ros-independent code should go to `package_main/library` src and include. Unfortunately by using the dynamic_reconfigure command ros creates the two directories `package_main/cfg` and `package_main/src`. Both is a bit awkward to me, since one may expect the `*.cfg` file in the `cfg` directory and the sources in the `src` directory.

Edit 2: Output of tree for better readability
Edit 3: Since it seems to be more complex, I created a minimal example, and edited respectively.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294862/dynamic-reconfigure-specific-directory/) by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-22**:
This directory listing is a little confusing. Can you please update your question with a copy and paste of the output of using `tree`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After looking at the example package you provided (and fixing some issues with it, please make sure things compile on your own machine in the future), I believe the following is the problem (from #q69583 in fact):

```
from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator import *
```

This is the line you would use for the old version of `dynamic_reconfigure`, ie: the one for `rosbuild`. For Catkin, the line should read:

```
from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *
```

note the `_catkin` suffix there.

I would suggest to take a look at the [How to Write Your First .cfg File](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile) tutorial, just to see whether the `.cfg` file contains some other `rosbuild`-isms.

---

Edit: changes to the pkg and files I had to make:

- the `.cfg` file was not executable
- the `Start()` prototype in the `.cpp` file did not agree with the one in the header
- the prototype for `Stop()` in the `.cpp` file included an extra `S`, prefixed to the class name
- the `CMakeLists.txt` referenced `Boost` twice without a `find_package(Boost ..)` anywhere
- the `CMakeLists.txt` referenced a non-existing `include` directory

In addition, with the Catkin version of the `dynamic_reconfigure` generator, the `cfg/cpp` directory should not be on the include path any longer.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-06-25**:
Sorry, I did some mistakes creating the package. However, the line `from dynamic_reconfigre.parameter_generator_catkin import *` did the trick. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

when one wants to use dynamic_reconfigure usually crates cfg folder as you did. You do not need `__init__.py` in the cfg folder.

after that you should call following in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
   cfg/params.cfg
)
```

To answer concrete on your questions.

You should never change default target locations of your files in ROS in that way you will just get problems. ROS will after building the workspace with the package automatically create in your `ros` folder `build` and `devel` subfolder. When you execute `source ros/devel/setup.bash` you will have all paths of your system set-up correctly.

1. They will be crate in the sub folder `ros/devel` all header files for cpp and modules for python
2. You will get your generated headers in `ros/devel/include/_package_name_/include`

For more detail see:
https://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces and https://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2018-06-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-06-21**:
Thanks for your reply, a few thoughts. 1. The **init**.py are empty and auto-generated. I don't want them, but `catkin build` always creates them. 2. ROS creates everything in devel as it should, but it also creates described files, hence I have two distinct src dirs, which confuses very much :-(

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-06-21**:\

1. This is something strange with your workspace. It would make sense to create a new and clean one.... I never got something like this....
2. Why do you have two distinct src dirs? Can you show your structure?

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-06-22**:\

1. I tried so, it's always the same, two empty **init**.py files.
2. I will update my structure in the old post, I made a mistake there, sorry.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-22**:
I agree with @destogl: generated sources (such as those for `dynamic_reconfigure`) should not show up in your package directory, but should go into the `devel` folder. The `cfg` dir you show at the top of your `tree` output, is that really where the `.h` ends up? Can you show your `CMakeLists.txt`?

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-06-22**:
What exactly is showing your updated structure? A package?

usually multiple `src` folders are not a problem if added correctly in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Could you show following:

1. Structure of your package before compilation,
2. Your `CMakeLists.txt` file and
3. Structure after compilation

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-06-22**:
I edited my original post again and tried to post the questioned parts. I had to delete a lot of generated files, hopefully you can see the problem?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-22**:
First thing I notice is that you have the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` in the workspace root, instead of in the source space. `unlink CMakeLists.txt` in your workspace root.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-22**:
I would also `rm -rf` the `pack_template/cfg/cpp` dir. It should not be there.

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-06-22**:
@gvdhoorn the `pack_template/cfg/cpp` is autogenerated and the reason why I created that thread. I don't want it, but it is always created.
What do you mean with `unlink CMakeLists.txt` I thought to follow the ROS Wiki Tutorial step by step? What's the problem with the file at the top-level?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-22**:
I can't make it any clearer: the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` should not be in the root of your workspace, but in the `src` sub-directory. As it is a symlink, you should use the `unlink` command to properly remove it.

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-06-22**:
Okay, I tried to do so, got it working, but my problem remains the same with the files being generated within my source space. However, thank you for the hint.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-22**:
Just for a test, can you place your `params.cfg` in the `cfg` directory itself. So in a directory that is a direct child of your package dir? Don't forget to update the `generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(..)` statement and what is currently in `cfg`. And `rm -rf build && rm -rf devel`.

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-06-22**:
I tried so (deleting everything before), unfortunately its still generating these files. May the problem be with the catkin configuration?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-22**:
Did you test putting your `params.cfg` in the location I suggested? Please be specific in your responses.

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-06-22**:
Also remove from `include_directories(..)` the following: `include`, `cfg/cpp`

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-06-22**:
@gvdhoorn Sorry, for being unspecific. Yes I moved the params.cfg file into the cfg dir, nothing changed.
@destogl I tried so, but this changes nothing but the `templateConfig.h` can not be found, since it is stored only at `cfg/cpp`. (gcc=>fata error No such file or directory)

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-06-22**:
There is something really strange wit your configuration. The best would be to update all ROS packages,  create new workspace and add your clean package again.... I have no other idea...

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-06-22**:
@destogl What do you mean with update ROS packages? apt-get update and upgrade or something else? I tried that already, I installed on another machine, its always the same, even with a new workspace.

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-06-23**:
Yes so mean that. I am creating new workspaces once per week and I never got such an error. I can pbly help you if you send me your package or you should follow tutorials again...

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-06-25**:
@destogl Thank you for your offer, how can I send the project to you?

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-06-25**:
Can you upload it somewhere and post a link for download?

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-06-25**:
I did so: [pack_template.tar.gz](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/522aa332916be5353edd4726f077f9f820180625065805/d5b8145fef639d8632afff40c88880b820180625065805/03cabd)